# Can I export symbols from the global module fragment?

Tags: c++, c++-modules

I have a C++20 module that defines some helper types and functions that wrap a C library. My primary module file looks like this:

```cpp
module; 
#include <the_c_library.h>
export module my_wrapper;
export class UsefulWrapper { ... };
...
```

Users of `my_wrapper` also usually need some of the symbols from `the_c_library.h`. I tried to re-export them, but got a compiler error. Is there a way to do this?

```cpp
...
export module my_wrapper;
export int some_c_function(const char *);  // I tried adding a line like this.
...
```

The compiler complains:

> declaration of 'some_c_function' in module my_wrapper follows declaration in the global module

I'm using clang (HEAD of main branch, so roughly version 17).

If I can't do this, then users will need to `#include <the_c_library.h>` in addition to `import my_wrapper`, which is not the end of the world, obviously. But I'd like to understand what is possible here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t redeclare entities from another module (including the global module), but you can export ***using-declaration*s** naming them so long as they have external linkage:

```
export using ::some_c_function;
```

The `::` seems redundant but is syntactically necessary: a *using-declarator* must use a *qualified-id*.  Note that you can’t select overloads this way, but you can choose whether to expose the name in its original **namespace** or in another one.

Comment: Technique buggy in GCC at this writing (fails to compile). See https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=109679 and https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=113129